# Vim: How to switch back from tabview to vertical split

Tags: macos, vim, vi

I can use `Ctrl+W T` to switch form vertical split to tabview.

My question is what can I use to switch back to vertical split / horizontal split for all tabs?

Comment: I always "re-split" before that command to avoid this problem

Comment: @Vitor can u please explain?

Comment: In the window with the buffer I want to open in a tab I press "ctrl-w s ctrl-w t". When I want to close the new tab I just run :q since the original tab is still as it was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that means to close all tabs except the previous one, and then reopen all windows on that tab.

```
nnoremap <silent><C-W>U :hide -tabonly <bar> unhide<CR>
```

Comment: This seams to work however it switches back to horizontal split than vertical split. Any idea how coould I adjust that?

Comment: @sramij Read `:h :vert`. E.g. `vert unhide`.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28313975/how-to-convert-split-windows-to-tabs-and-vice-versa-in-vim) may be useful for you.

You can alternatively work with buffers. Do a `:ls` to find the buffer number of the file you are editing in another tab (it is the number in the first column). Then you can bring the tab to a split by using the `:bufdo cmd`.
For example, to bring file with buffer 4 into a vertical split you would do `:4bufdo vs`.

This howerver does not close the previous tab.